# How to configure java application having 2 log4j2.xml files so that both configurations work fine

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

We are running a `Java` file named `Calc.java` and for this application, we are using `log4j2.xml` file for logging to a file named `LogCalc.txt`. Our `Calc.java` is using a **.jar file** named `Addition.Jar`, which is composed of `Add.java`, which also uses `log4j2.xml` file for its own logging to a file named `LogAdd.txt`.

The question here is, when we run `Calc.java` and access a method from `Addition.Jar`, **logging is only happening** in `LogCalc.txt`, the configurations in `log4j2.xml` of `Calc.java` is taken into account and `log4j2.xml` of `LogAdd.txt` is not taken into account. Due to this I am not able to get logs from `Addition.jar`, **`LogAdd.txt` is empty**.

How can we change our configurations such that we can see both logs from `Calc.java` in `LogCalc.txt` as well as from `Add.java` in `LogAdd.txt`, i.e., both `XML` configurations must work fine in our application and both of them logging to different files with their own configurations taken from respective `XML` files).

Our aim here is to make a project where main app uses `log4j2.xml` and also the included **.jar** in this project is using `log4j2.xml`, but we should get logs from both of them to their respective appenders separately without any problem.

Our Xml files look like this. log4j2.xml used in Addition.jar is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="A1" fileName="A1.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The log4j2.xml file used with Calc.java is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="A1" fileName="A1.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Could you try to simplify the question focusing on the problem while showing us some code and expose problem in it?

Comment: @ KernelPanic  To simplify, we are using a test code which uses log4j2.xml file for logging and this includes a library (Jar file) which itself uses another log4j2.xml file for its logging. So when we run this, we want both xml configurations to work fine independent of each other. So that both can log to their own appeders.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j will locate the first log4j2.xml that it finds on the classpath and use that for configuration. It does not currently support multiple configurations, although work is in progress to allow it to. Even if it did it would not work the way your configuration won't work because the loggers are the same.

I suggest you review the log4j guide online. Log4j does not log on the basis of jar files but by comparing the names of the loggers you are using against what is configured.  If you want everything in one jar to go to one file then use a logger name such as Calc for the first jar and a logger name of LogCalc for the second jar. Then have your configuration route the events for each of the loggers to the appropriate files.

Comment: understood that loggers must have different name.  But we are unable to get both xml configurations working fine independently. Only the main app's log4j2.xml file is being used for logging. still not able to get the log4j2.xml configuration of Addition.jar running correctly. Is that because of root loggers? Can  you please help?

Comment: It is because Log4j will only use the first log4j2.xml it finds.  The log4j2.xml needs to contain the configuration required for your whole application.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. What about the other xml file which is in the jar file included. How to make it work? We need both xml files configurations working. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no way to do that currently. Log4j is contemplating adding support for composite configuration, but even then the configurations above would not work the way you want.